# On ubuntu 20.04 trying to suspend my laptop the system freezes

Tags: 20.04, suspend, freeze

Yesterday there was an update of my 20.04. After that, when I try to sleep, the laptop freezes, the screen glows. Then after a while it reboots.

The same thing happens if i put to sleep with the command:

```
systemctl suspend
```

My Laptop - Legion Y540-15IRH-PG0 Intel and nVidia GeForce GTX 1650

Please advise where to look to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by myself
Installed another driver

```
apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
apt install nvidia-headless-515
```